# number base decoded message

Tags: decode, encode, radix

I have this piece of decoded message, it's a homework but i can't solve it, the message is

`IZWGCZZ2EBAUWRSVOJAU45DSOVCEOZKS
N5CHKQLSM5GGSQ2VNVIECUSEIU======`

there is a hint saying `The string is encoded using an unusual number base. The numbers 2 - 7 are represented and the letters A - Z are represented.`

i have looked into the internet but i couldn't find anything, please if anyone could help understand this problem and solve it i would appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see: `A-Z` + `2-7` = `32` possible values.

32 values can be contained in `5 bits`, thus each byte of the message represents 5 bits.

To decode, each of those `5 bits` have to be put together in one long *bit-string* which is then read as an `8 bit ASCII` string.

Or, in other words: `Base32 encoding`.

So:

```
IZWGCZZ2EBAUWRSVOJAU45DSOVCEOZKSN5CHKQLSM5GGSQ2VNVIECUSEIU======
```

converts to:

```
Flag: AKFUrANtruDGeRoDuArgLiCUmPARDE
```

See [here](http://emn178.github.io/online-tools/base32_decode.html) to test the decoding.

Comment: Thank you so much, i have used a base32 decoding tool but it didn't work for me because i was including the '=' with the code  thank you so much my friend

Comment: No problem, glad to help :) (the `=` are used to fill out te data - in your case it's 64 bytes).